# Conditional Median In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to find the median home price each year from a long list of home sales.
The following image shows a simplified example, and it's not correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to find the median for each year.

Please use:

```
=MEDIAN(QUERY($B$2:$C$7,"select C where B="&B10&"",0))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`MEDIAN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094025)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much marikamitsos

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you for taking the time to accept.